# Kotlin - lambda argument outside parenthesis

Tags: kotlin, lambda

having following function

```
fun functionOne(element: Int, func1: (index: Int) -> Unit) {
    println("element=$element")
    func1(element)
}
```

I can call it that way:

```
functionOne(element = 123, func1 = {index -> println("index: $index")})
```

no compilator complains

```
functionOne(123,  {index -> println("index: $index")})
```

now compilator suggests `Lambda argument should be moved out of parentheses`

or

```
functionOne(123) { index -> println("index: $index") }
```

no complains

however, unless I don't get it right, this begavior is limited to exactly one lambda argument, that is having

```
fun functionTwo(element: Int, func1: (index: Int) -> Unit, func2: (index: Int) -> Unit) {
    println("element=$element")
    func1(element)
    func2(element)
}
```

I can make a call like this

```
functionTwo(123, { index -> println("index: $index")},  { index -> println("index2: $index")})
```

but this one does not compile

```
functionTwo(456) {index -> println("index: $index"} { index -> println("index2: $index")})
```

can you please confirm that or let me know to move lambda arguments out of parentheses

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas), only trailing lambdas can be placed outside the parenthesis:

> **Passing trailing lambdas**
>
> According to Kotlin convention, if the last parameter of a function is a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding argument can be placed outside the parentheses:
>
> ```
> val product = items.fold(1) { acc, e -> acc * e }
> ```
>
> Such syntax is also known as *trailing lambda*.
>
> If the lambda is the only argument in that call, the parentheses can be omitted entirely:
>
> ```
> run { println("...") }
> ```

This implies that you can not move the second-to-last lambda expression outside of the parenthesis, and thus that you cannot move multiple lambda expressions out of the parenthesis.

Comment: Such a strange pattern/bit of syntax.

Comment: makes it worse with the _with_ method. 

```kotlin
fun withWith() : String {
    return with(StringBuilder()) {
        this.append("s")
        this.append("b")
        this.toString()
    }
}
```
The function body after _with_ is actually just a _trailing lambda_ and not a function body

PS. formatting sucks in comments